# App crashes when using allKeys, is it because there is only one object?

Tags: iphone, xcode, exception, error-handling, nsdictionary

I can't figure out why xcode continues to throw this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    
[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9367330'
```

whenever I use this code

```
NSDictionary *nextArray = [_classDictionary 
valueForKeyPath:@"response.page_records.page_record"];
for (NSDictionary *roster2 in nextArray) {
NSArray *keys = [roster2 allKeys];
if ([keys containsObject:@"title"]){
    [pageName addObject:[roster2 objectForKey:@"title"]];
}
if ([keys containsObject:@"id"]) {
[pageID addObject:[roster2 objectForKey:@"id"]];
}
}
```

After trying to debug it I found out that the exception is only thrown when there is only one object for the key.  For example when "nextArray" is this:

```
 (
 {
    "class_id" = 0001;
    "id" = 1234;
    "title" = "First Page";
},
{
     "class_id" = 0002;
     "id" = 12345;
     "title" = Assignments;
 }
 )
```

the code runs without an exception, but when the code is simply

```
      {
         "class_id" = 0001;
         "id" = 1234;
         "title" = "First Page";
     }
```

The exception is thrown.  Why would this be happening?  The keys still contains the object title, even if there is only one object.  Any other ideas why this exception is being thrown?  Does it have something to do with the parenthesis? (total guess)  Is there a better way to debug what is really going on?

EDIT:  Here is the _userDictionary.  What is the best way to have an ordered array of the objectforKey: @"title" and avoid the above error?

```
response =     {
    "status" = ok;
    "page_records" =         {
        "page" = 1;
        "page_count" = 1;
        "records_per_page" = 50;
        "total_record_count" = 2;
        "page_record" =             (
                            {
                "class_id" = 0001;
                "id" = 1234;
                "title" = "Test page";
            },
                            {
                "class_id" = 0002;
                "id" = 12345;
                "title" = "testing page 2";
            }
        );
    };
};
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I'm making progress as to why this is happening I just don't have a solution.  Is it because the data with only one "title" is being treated as an NSArray and NSArray does not have the allKeys selector?

Comment: no, it says that its trying to call it on a NSString

Comment: I added the dictionary, is there an alternative to my code that would let me get the objectforKey:@"title" and avoid the above error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you are iterating through an array of dictionaries, and hence, `NSArray *keys = [roster2 allKeys];` is being called upon an array. However, in your second example, you have just *one* dictionary. It is *not* an array of dictionaries. So your loop `for (NSDictionary *roster2 in nextArray)` is iterating through the keys of your dictionary, which are just strings, and not arrays. Hence, the error.

First of all, your naming is confusing. An `NSDictionary` named `nextArray`? Try this:

```
id *response = [_classDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"response.page_records.page_record"];  
NSMutableArray *records;  

if ([response isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
    records = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [records addObject: response];
}
else {
    records = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: response];
}

for (NSDictionary *roster2 in records) {
    NSArray *keys = [roster2 allKeys];
    if ([keys containsObject:@"title"]){
        [pageName addObject:[roster2 objectForKey:@"title"]];
    }
    if ([keys containsObject:@"id"]) {
        [pageID addObject:[roster2 objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so that is why, but is there a solution?  My NSDictionary _classDictionary is converted XML data.  All I want is an ordered array of the objectsforkey "title", even if there is only one object for that key.

Comment: I added the _classDictionary.  Can you suggest how I should change my code to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's because `NSString` doesn't respond to `allKeys`. The console log tells you this--you need to read it more carefully.

In NeXT-style plists, `({})` defines an array containing a dictionary. `{}` defines *just* a dictionary. That is, this:

```
{
    "class_id" = 0001;
    "id" = 1234;
    "title" = "First Page";
}
```

Is *not* structurally the same as this:

```
(
    {
        "class_id" = 0001;
        "id" = 1234;
        "title" = "First Page";
    }
)
```

Even though they contain the same information. Even if you have only one element in your root array, you still need to tell the plist parser that there is an array there, so you need to include `(` and `)` for your logic to handle it correctly.

**Edit:** Given the information in your comment, the solution will not be quite so simple. If your source data is arbitrary that way, you'll need to check the type of the data to see if it's an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, and handle it appropriately. For example:

```
id myData = [self plistFromArbitrarySource];
if (myData) {
    if ([myData isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in myData) {
            [self parseDictionary:dict];
        }
    } else if ([myData isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]]) {
        [self parseDictionary:myData];
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'm using an XMLReader plugin to convert XML to an NSDictionary.  The converted NSDictionary "_classDictionary" does not have parenthesis.  When I use valueForKeyPath, parenthesis are inserted when there is more than one value for that key path.  It sounds like I need to add parenthesis when there is only one value for the key path, am I understanding what is going on, and is this possible?

Comment: I added the _classDictionary.  Can you suggest how I should change this code to avoid this error?

Comment: The parentheses indicate an *array*, ***not*** a dictionary. They're different data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The error message contains everything you need to know:

```
[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector
```

It means that you're trying to call the method `allKeys` on an instance of `NSString`.

Let's look at where you call `allKeys`:

```
for (NSDictionary *roster2 in nextArray) {
    NSArray *keys = [roster2 allKeys];
```

`roster2` is an instance of NSString, not NSDictionary.  You're expecting `nextArray` to contain `NSDictionary` objects, but it instead contains `NSString` objects.

Comment: I added the _classDictionary.  Can you suggest how to change my code to get the `valueForKey: @"title"` and avoid this error?